# Cant get the CUDA-module to work under OpenCV 3.0 Beta

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

For the life of it i cant get the CUDA-modules to work under OpenCV3.0 Beta with Visual Studio 2013 64Bit Professional, CUDA SDK 6.5 and Win7 64Bit. My used example code worked flawlessly half a year ago with OpenCV3.0 Alpha. Now i cant even get cv::cuda::flip to work; the code works till it should be uploading the Mat to CUDA but then it stops working.

Can somebody please provide a working example code, so i can see where im overlooking something?

All the steps i did before:

After building OpenCV3.0Beta with CUDA and OpenGL enabled with CMake and MSVC2013 Professional, i built OpenCV.sln in Debug and Release /X64 Config (which says successfully build: 266 each). After that i each built INSTALL.vcxproj in Debug/Release X64-Config in the modules/smaples/include and data-folder so it all gets copied to the install-folder.

Under Properties C++ General:

D:\OpenCV\GebautmitCUDAohneTBB\install\include
D:\Programme\glew-1.12.0\include
D:\Programme\freeglut\include

Under Properties Linker General:

D:\OpenCV\GebautmitCUDAohneTBB\install\x64\vc12\lib
D:\Programme\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\x64
D:\Programme\freeglut\lib\x64

Under Properties Linker Input:

the usual OpenCV-libs,
glew32.lib,
freeglut.lib

Here my example code:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER && _MSC_VER >= 1400
#pragma warning(disable : 4100)
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/cuda.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

int main() {
/*
if (getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() == 0)
{
return cerr << "No GPU found or the library is compiled without CUDA  support" << endl, -1;
}

cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::cuda::getDevice());
*/
Mat image, image2, imagedownloaded, demoimage, grayimage;

image = imread("fruits.jpg", 1);

if (image.channels() == 1)
{
    cout << "1 channel";
}
else
{
    cout << "3 channel";
}

cv::cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

GpuMat image_gpu, gray_gpu, demo_gpu, image_gpu2;

image_gpu2.upload(image);

cv::cuda::demosaicing(image_gpu2, demo_gpu, COLOR_BayerGR2BGR, 3);

demo_gpu.download(demoimage);

if (demoimage.channels() == 1)
{
    cout << "1 channel";
}
else
{
    cout << "3 channel";
}

imshow("bla2", image);
imshow("bla3", demoimage);
waitKey();
return 0;

}
```

Can somebody please point out what i forgot, so it will work again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem: 
I found out that my code and the opencv-gpu-samples dont work for about 1 minute, but after that time it works flawless. So i searched for this problem on google and found out, that is had to be the case that CUDA apparently needs to compile the code during runtime once again to get their Cubin/PTX-files to work on the gpu properly (my understanding of it).

So i looked at my CMake-Configuration (standard-config from Opencv/Source) and it just builds OpenCV-CUDA-Config with Arch-Bins 1.0 - 3.0, while i have a GTX970 which has a 5.2 compute ability.

After changing the CMake-CUDA-Arch-Bin and PTX-Setting to 5.0 and building OpenCV with CUDA and OpenGL once again, CUDA runs just fine and with the expected speed :)
Also the buildtime for OpenCV with CUDA decreased immensely (because of only one Arch-Bin/PTX-Build-Setting) from 2h to 25min.